# SQL: Querying Against Composite Entity

Tags: sql, join

[image: Example]

I'm trying to figure out how to query against a composite key.

In my select result, I want the book name, author, category, and selling price. So far I have `select title,category,price from books1 where books1.category='MYS';`

but I'm not sure how to go about getting the author name.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the system you are actually using.

Comment: I don't see a composite entity or a composite key anywhere in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have books1 when the model show the table named books.  Books is a horrible name for a table -- typically in relational databases you use the singular -- eg book.

Here is how you do a join:

```
Select a.First, a.Last 
from books b
join books_authors ab on b.b_code = ab.book_code
join authors a on ab.authorId = a.id
where b.category = 'MYS'
```

also all of your field names have spaces in them -- I don't know what platform you are using so I've no idea how to escape the names.  Using spaces in field name is non-standard and not acually SQL. I'd advise against it whenever possible.